# Joystick in win32 application, winmm

Tags: c++, winapi, input, joystick, winmm

How should I understand this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757116%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Can I only use 4 buttons and 1 analog stick? I've got a gamepad with 12 buttons, 2 analog joysticks and one "steering cross" (POV hat?). How many of these buttons can I use with winmm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need more axis than are supported by winmm, consider DirectInput.

However, the page you linked clearly states that up to 32 buttons and 6 axes (3 2-D analog sticks) are supported by winmm.  Looks like your gamepad will max out on axes, using all 6, and also use 12 out of 32 buttons.

Comment: I think this refers to "Extended capabilities" which i don't know what it is. Because there isn't any defines for JOY_BUTTON5CHG etc. and MM_JOY1MOVE doesn't differentiate between sticks in any way I can see.

Comment: @Moberg: The "extended capabilities" are provided by the "Ex" flavor of the API.  `joyGetPosEx` is the extended version of `joyGetPos`.  `JOYINFOEX` is the extended version of `JOYINFO`.

Comment: Can I capture these extension buttons or do I need to query them? Query means calling joyGetPos(Ex) regularly so that the JOYINFOEX struct gets updated to see the state of the gamepad?

Comment: I would like to handle the joystick input in the message loop as I do with all keyboard and mouse input.

Comment: @Moberg: I think you'll need to poll, or switch to DirectInput.  Most applications using extended joysticks have a draw loop (aka game loop) anyway and for these polling is convenient.

Comment: I can use (wParam & JOY_BUTTON10) to see if button 10 is held down, but pressing the button won't trigger a windows event (at least not a MM_JOY1BUTTONDOWN message).

Comment: OK thank you, maybe I can manage without all buttons, at least for a while. :)

Comment: You can use joySetCapture to have Windows send joystick events to the message loop.

Comment: @rdb: clearly you missed the entire point of the question.  `joySetCapture` will only send message for the first four buttons and first three axes.  All the rest of the events are lost.